# How to delete web users in plesk?

Tags: ssh, centos, plesk

Today, I've received this issue

> "El número de usuarios web excede el límite definido por su licencia.
>   Dispone de 4 usuarios web mientras que su licencia le permite disponer
>   de 1"

I need delete 3 web users with ssh, but I don´t know how can I do.

Can you help me?

**I use plesk 9.3.0 and CentOS.**

Tahnks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Don't forget to backup web user's data

You can try to did it from CLI:

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/webuser --remove mywebuser  -domain example.tld
```

In case CLI blocked by license issue, you can try to delete it manually via database, for example I'd like to delete `mywebuser`:

```
# mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` -Dpsa -e "select login, account_id, sys_user_id from sys_users join accounts on account_id=accounts.id join web_users on sys_user_id = sys_users.id where sys_users.login ='mywebuser'"
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| login     | account_id | sys_user_id |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| mywebuser |         36 |          10 |
+-----------+------------+-------------+

# mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` -Dpsa -e "delete from web_users where sys_user_id = 10"
# mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` -Dpsa -e "delete from accounts where id = 36"
# mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` -Dpsa -e "delete from sys_users where login = 'mywebuser'"
```

Delete users's data:

```
# rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/web_users/mywebuser
```

Delete system user:

```
# userdel mywebuser
```